# Interpolate new values using a set of samples

Tags: r, curve-fitting, linear-regression

I'm new to R. Having a set of samples along with the target, I want to fit a numeric function to solve the target of new samples. My sample is time in seconds indicating the duration of a user's staying at this place:

```
>b <- c(101,25711,13451,19442,26,3083,133,184,4403,9713,6918,10056,12201,10624,14984,5241,
+21619,44285,3262,2115,1822,11291,3243,12989,3607,12882,4462,11553,7596,2926,12955,
+1832,3539,6897,13571,16668,813,1824,10304,2508,1493,4407,7820,507,15866,7442,7738,
+5705,2869,10137,11276,12884,11298,...)
```

Firstly, I convert them to hours dividing by 3600, and I want to fit a function as pdf of the duration:

```
> b <- b/3600
> hist(c,xlim=c(0,13),prob=T,breaks=seq(0,24,by=0.5))
> lines(density(x), col=red)
```

[image]

I want to fit the red line on the figure, and interpolate new values to find the probability of the specific duration on this place say p(duration = 1.5hours).

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: Try `MASS:fitdistr` or `optim` if you know the likelihood function of your distribution.

Comment: ...and note that the probability density at a single point is zero, you have to define a region, i.e. `p(duration < 1.6 and duration > 1.4)`.

Comment: Why not to use the `density`.. something like `dd <- density(b);sum(dd$y[dd$x <1.5])/sum(dd$y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested above, you can fit a distribution with `fitdistr` in `MASS` package.
If you use a continuous distribution you will have the probability that the time is within an interval. If you use a discrete distribution, you may compute the probability of a certain time (in hours).

For the continuous case, you can use a Gamma distribution: `fitdistr(b, "Gamma")` will give you the parameter estimates, and then you can use `pgamma` with those estimates and an interval.

For the discrete case, you can use a Poisson distribution: `fitdistr(b, "Poisson")` and then the `dpois` function with the estimate and the value you want.

To decide which one to use, I'd just plot the pdf with the histogram and take a look.

Comment: I think we should be more careful here... Why are you choosing a gamma distribution? His density can be anything. Without further knowledge, I'd suggest a non-parametric density estimator, using kernels or maybe just the histogram.

Comment: Yeah. I just said gamma by looking at the histogram he provided. Of course that is something to consider, but I guess it's up to him to decide what is _sufficiently_ correct.